# Wordpress - Adding dashboard icon to margin

Tags: wordpress

I want adding for #adminmenu div.wp-menu-image - adding **margin**, but I do not know where would get the chance (one css file). Anyone who knows where to add, please help and thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually the theme's main css file is located in the folder of the theme. You can add your css there or edit the existing css. The path is almost always wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/style.css

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not at all does not work either.